# Alinear divs usando bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```html
<?php
 include "header.php";

  require 'conexion.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 
 <meta name="decription" content="etiquetas html5">
 
 
</head>

 <div class="shoes-grid">
  <div class="products">
   <h5 class="latest-product">Listado de Productos</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="product-left">
   
<?php

 $link = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'catalogo');
 $sql = 'SELECT p.idProducto, p.prdNombre, p.prdPrecio, m.mkNombre, c.catNombre, p.prdPresentacion, p.prdStock, p.prdImagen
            FROM productos AS p
            INNER JOIN marcas AS m
            ON m.idMarca = p.idMarca
            INNER JOIN categorias AS c

            ON c.idCategoria = p.idCategoria
            ORDER BY idProducto';
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die( mysqli_error($link) );
    mysqli_close($link);

    while ( $fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ) ){

?>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 chain-grid">
    <a href="?page=producto"><img src="images/productos/<?php echo $fila['prdImagen']; ?>" class="img-responsive"></a>
     <div class="grid-chain-bottom">
     <h6><a href="#"><?php echo $fila['prdNombre']; ?></a></h6>
    
     <h6><a href="?page=producto">Presentacion:<?php echo $fila['prdPresentacion'];  ?></a></h6>
     <div class="star-price">
      <div class="dolor-grid"> 
       <span class="actual">Precio:<?php echo $fila['prdPrecio'];  ?></span>
       <br>
       <span class="actual">Stock:<?php echo $fila['prdStock'];  ?> </span>
      </div> 
      <a class="now-get get-cart" href="?page=producto">VER MÁS</a> 
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <?php
}
?>
   
   <div class="clearfix"></div> 
    </div>
  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
 
 </div> 
 </html>
 <div class="col-md-8"> 
   
 <?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

*el código que tengo muestra los divs correctamente,(con toda la información de la base de datos) pero la posición es el problema, solo muestra dos divs en una fila , y deja un espacio vacio al lado derecho , luego en la otra fila lo mismo siempre mostrando solo dos divs hasta acabar , estoy usando bootstrap para la estructura , pero no se si podría arreglarlo asi o solo con una hoja de css

Comment: Asegurate que las filas (row) contengan 3 divs con clase col-sm-4 o col-md-4 dependiendo de lo que usas.

Answer (score 1):

Como hay codigo PHP y MYSQLi, no podremos verificar en el snippet si funciona o no.

Te recomiendo utilizar:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
```

Para contener lo que seria el "contenido"

En tu codigo no tienes el cierre de `<div class="col-md-8">`

Aquí estas dividiendo el contenido en 2:
*columna de 4 y columna de 8.*

Si quieres 3 divs, tienes que dividir 12 (el total definido por bootstrap `width:100%;` en 3).

Es decir, tres `col-md-4.`

`Posible Solución`: (Si sobra espacio)

Puedes utilizar offset que brinda [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

> Mueve las columnas hacia la derecha usando las clases .offset-md- *. Estas clases aumentan el margen izquierdo de una columna por * columnas. Por ejemplo, .offset-md-4 mueve .col-md-4 en cuatro columnas.

```
.offset-md-4
```

Lee el archivo de [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).